# Import XML file with Header, Detail, and Trailer section in SSIS

Tags: sql, xml, ssis, xsd

I am attempting to load an XML file through SSIS. I want to note that I did generate the XSD through SSIS. Here is the sample file which I was able to load successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ACOParticipantData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <HeaderCode>HDR_PRVDR</HeaderCode>
    <FileCreationDate>20160101</FileCreationDate>
    <ACOProgCode>21</ACOProgCode>
  </Header>
  <Participants>
    <Participant>
      <ACO_ID>V199</ACO_ID>
     <TIN>123456789</TIN>
      <Old_TIN>987654321</Old_TIN>
      <Org_NPI>1234567890</Org_NPI>
      <Ind_NPI>1234567890</Ind_NPI>
      <CCN>123456</CCN>
      <PRG_Eff_Dt>20160101</PRG_Eff_Dt>
      <PRG_Term_Dt>20161231</PRG_Term_Dt>
      <ErrorCode>44</ErrorCode>
    </Participant>
  </Participants>
  <Trailer>
    <TrailerCode>TRL_PRVDR</TrailerCode>
    <FileCreationDate>20160101</FileCreationDate>
    <RecordCount>1</RecordCount>
  </Trailer>
</ACOParticipantData>
```

The production file has the same format but I am now receiving the below error in SSIS:

> [XML Source [79]] Error: The XML Source was unable to process the XML
>   data. The Xml source document contains the "xsi:nil" attribute with a
>   value of true on the "Old_TIN" element, therefore the element must be
>   empty.

However, there doesn't seem to be anything erroneous about the source file. How would one go about debugging and ingesting this file successfully?

EDIT:
Out of the two production files, I've altered the smaller one slightly but it will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ACOParticipantData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
    <HeaderCode>HDR_PRVDR</HeaderCode>
    <FileCreationDate>20160602</FileCreationDate>
    <ACOProgCode>21</ACOProgCode>
</Header>
<Participants xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Participant>
        <ACO_ID>V130</ACO_ID>
        <TIN>123456789</TIN>
        <Old_TIN xsi:nil="true">
        </Old_TIN>
        <Org_NPI xsi:nil="true">
        </Org_NPI>
        <Ind_NPI>0987654321</Ind_NPI>
        <CCN xsi:nil="true">
        </CCN>
        <PRG_Eff_Dt>20160101</PRG_Eff_Dt>
        <PRG_Term_Dt>20160601</PRG_Term_Dt>
        <ErrorCode>00</ErrorCode>
    </Participant>
    <Participant>
        <ACO_ID>V130</ACO_ID>
        <TIN>111222333</TIN>
        <Old_TIN xsi:nil="true">
        </Old_TIN>
        <Org_NPI xsi:nil="true">
        </Org_NPI>
        <Ind_NPI>4445556667</Ind_NPI>
        <CCN xsi:nil="true">
        </CCN>
        <PRG_Eff_Dt>20160101</PRG_Eff_Dt>
        <PRG_Term_Dt>20160601</PRG_Term_Dt>
        <ErrorCode>00</ErrorCode>
    </Participant>
</Participants>
<Trailer>
    <TrailerCode>TRL_PRVDR</TrailerCode>
    <FileCreationDate>20160602</FileCreationDate>
    <RecordCount>2</RecordCount>
</Trailer>
</ACOParticipantData>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `xsi:nil="true"` in your *real data XML*.

Being empty or being `NULL` is close but not exactly the same. In some cases this is needed to be distinguished.

If an element is marked as `NULL` like - in your case probably: `<Old_TIN xsi:nil="true">` there should be no value for this element.

If there is the `xsi:nil` flag **and** a value it's a contradiction...

### UPDATE

According to your edits you find this there (reduced)

```
<Participant>
    <Old_TIN xsi:nil="true">
    </Old_TIN>
    <Org_NPI xsi:nil="true">
    </Org_NPI>
    <CCN xsi:nil="true">
    </CCN>
</Participant>
```

These elements are not `NULL`, they contain a line break and spaces... Try change this to

```
<Participant>
    <Old_TIN xsi:nil="true"/>
    <Org_NPI xsi:nil="true"/>
    <CCN xsi:nil="true"/>
</Participant>
```

Comment: Right, I see that it would be a contraction if say a tag were to contain  `<Old_TIN xsi:nil="true">` followed by a value like `123456789` and then the closing tag `</Old_TIN>` however I don't see any instance of that in the data despite the error message indicating there is...

Comment: @jaguin It could look like being empty, but isn't (a space between the tags or a line break...) Are there many occurences of `xsi:nil="true"`? If not you might try to set them to an empty tag manually (`<Old_TIN xsi:nil="true"/>` with no closing tag) How big is your XML? Is it possible to show it somewhere?

Comment: I've made an edit to the main post and added a modified version of the production file.

Comment: The file was loaded successfully thanks to your input Shnugo. I expect the source files to be consistent with the contradiction thus I might have to design some logic to correct the files whenever there is a NULL value...